# SQL Server query date and amount

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create an SQL query which is based on the following info.

I have an amount bought and sold for each day for articles. I am trying to have a query that shows:

Total "amount" per "article" per "month

"amount" should be split into "positive total" and "negative total", summing up all positive "amount" and all negative "amount" separately.

THe date has the format "yyyy-mm-dd 00:00:00.000"

I tried the following

```
SELECT article, date, SUM (amount) Total FROM shop group by FORMAT(date, 'yyyy_MM'), article
```

I get the following message

"date is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause"

If I take the date out of the query everything works fine and it calculates the totals.

Comment: Voted to close as unclear because there is no sample data.

Answer (score 1):

You need a so-called *injective function* for your dates: way to convert all dates in a month to the same value, and you need to use it *both* in your SELECT and GROUP BY clauses.  [LAST_DAY()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_last-day) is a decent function to use. So is `DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m')`, by the way.

Try this:

```
   SELECT article, LAST_DAY(date) month_ending, SUM (amount) Total 
     FROM shop
    GROUP BY LAST_DAY(date), article
```

There's a general writeup of solutions to this problem [here](https://www.plumislandmedia.net/mysql/sql-reporting-time-intervals/).

Answer (score 1):

### Original answer for MySQL

There are mainly two mistakes in your query:

1. `FORMAT` is a function that converts a number to a string. So, MySQL will convert your date to a number first (which should not even be possible and raise an error, but MySQL does convert it to some number nonetheless) and then make sense of the format 'yyyy_MM', maybe taking MM to mean Myanmar, I don't know. I assume you get a different value for each day, instead of one value per month. You want `DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m')` instead.
2. You try to group by month, but then you display the date. Which date? A month has up to 31 different dates. You must display the month you grouped by instead (i.e. again `DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m')`).

As to separating positive and negative amounts, you can use conditional aggrgation, i.e. `CASE WHEN` inside the aggregation function (`SUM`).

```
SELECT
  DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m') AS month,
  article,
  SUM(CASE WHEN amount > 0 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS positive_total,
  SUM(CASE WHEN amount < 0 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS negative_total
FROM shop
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m'), article
ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m'), article;
```

### Updated answer for SQL Server

In SQL Server `FORMAT(date, 'yyyy_MM')` *is* a function to get the year and month from a date. The query is hence:

```
SELECT
  FORMAT(date, 'yyyy_MM') AS month,
  article,
  SUM(CASE WHEN amount > 0 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS positive_total,
  SUM(CASE WHEN amount < 0 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS negative_total
FROM shop
GROUP BY FORMAT(date, 'yyyy_MM'), article
ORDER BY FORMAT(date, 'yyyy_MM'), article;
```

Comment: I would alos need to group by another variable defining the "article type". So each artcile could be in 2 different "article types". Would I just need to add that by "Groupy by" before "article"?

Comment: Yep, just add the type to the `SELECT`, `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` clauses.

Comment: I gt the message "DATE_FORMAT" is not a recognized built-in function name?

Comment: You have tagged your request with the DBMS MySQL, which supports this function (see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format). If you get this error, you are probably using some other DBMS. Oracle? SQL Server? PostgreSQL? ...

Comment: I use SQL Server Management Studio..sorry

Comment: Then use the format function you originally used. I've updated my answer. I've also updated the tags for your request.